# JavaScript Full Screen in Window Mode

Tags: javascript, browser

There is a site that I go on and it requires me to be in full screen mode and if I leave full screen it cancels out what I am doing on the site. Is there a way I could modify my FireFox or Safari browser to trick the JavaScript to let me have it in a window mode so I can leave it without it knowing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
window.onload = maxWindow;

    function maxWindow() {
        window.moveTo(0, 0);


        if (document.all) {
            top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
        }

        else if (document.layers || document.getElementById) {
            if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth) {
                top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
                top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will be useful for you this website that does exactly what you wanna.

http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/